# why IOKit can cause race condition after lck_mtx_lock/lck_mtx_unlock

Tags: security, race-condition, iokit

when do something with a iokit object handle in userland, example IOConnectCallmethod

going to Kernel through a mach_msg,one of mach_trap,

(same with other MIG call)-> util before call is_io_connect_method,There's an operation to convert ipc_port to iokit object

```
connection = iokit_lookup_connect_port(In0P->Head.msgh_request_port);
```

and iokit_lookup_connect_port inside:

```
MIGEXTERN io_object_t
iokit_lookup_connect_port( ipc_port_t   port){
register io_object_t    obj;

if (!IP_VALID(port))
    return (NULL);

iokit_lock_port(port);
if (ip_active(port) && (ip_kotype(port) == IKOT_IOKIT_CONNECT)) {
    obj = (io_object_t) port->ip_kobject;
    iokit_add_connect_reference( obj );
}
else
    obj = NULL;

iokit_unlock_port(port);

return( obj );
}
```

each successful call must call iokit_lock_port and iokit_unlock_port

```
EXTERN void
iokit_lock_port( __unused ipc_port_t port )
{
    lck_mtx_lock(&iokit_obj_to_port_binding_lock);
}

EXTERN void
iokit_unlock_port( __unused ipc_port_t port )
{
    lck_mtx_unlock(&iokit_obj_to_port_binding_lock);
}
```

but why still can cause race condition even when call a same IOKit method?

i tried if i add code of lock inside IOKit method,or before the method of race condition, lock can protect successful,
But why lock inside iokit_lock_port/iokit_unlock_port cannot?